# How to use CASE Clause in Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getEntityClass());
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("preview", 1));
            return criteria.list();
```

how to add a projection "case when id = 1 then 'one ' else '0' end as custom " ;

something similar to this ,

```
select * , case when id = 1 then 'one ' else '0' end as custom from table where preview = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it over JPA interfaces without Hibernate spesific classes.I hope it'll work for you.I tested it on my local and it is working

```
public static List<String> getUndeliveredPartnerRequests() throws Exception{

        EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.instanceEMF().createEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
            Root<YourEntity> entityObj = query.from(YourEntity.class);
            query.multiselect(
                    cb.selectCase()
                    .when(cb.equal(entityObj.get("preview"), 1), "one")
                    .when(cb.equal(entityObj.get("preview"), 2), "two")
                    .otherwise("wrong"));

            Query q = em.createQuery(query);
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
 }
```